# Filtering rows in Pandas Groupby based on a condition within the group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I've been wrestling with this for a couple of days now, despite a lot of searching. I've come across a number of similar problems, but I've not been able to make any of the solutions work for me.

Here's my starting dataframe:

```
data = {
"account_id": ["1001", "1001", "1002", "1002", "1002", "1002", "1002", "1003", "1003", "1003"],
"data_type": ["initial_balance", "payment", "payment", "initial_balance", "payment", "payment", "payment", "payment", "initial_balance", "payment"],
"transaction_date": ["2022-04-01", "2022-04-14", "2022-03-01", "2022-04-02", "2022-04-13", "2022-05-01", "2022-05-03", "2022-03-13", "2022-04-10", "2022-04-20"],
"amount": [100, -20, -30, 200, -20, -20, -20, -10, 150, -50],}
```

Which, once in Pandas becomes:

[df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quNY0.png)

I'm looking to group by `account_id` and remove any entry before the entry with `data_type` = "initial_balance". Once I've got this, I can then `cumsum` over the remaining group rows to get to the current balance. So the desired outcome (including the `cumsum` "account_balance" column) is:

[Desired result including the `cumsum` "account_balance" column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVe9b.png)

I've tried the following:

```
df.groupby("account_id").filter(lambda x:x["transaction_date"]>=x[x["data_type"]=="initial_balance"]["transaction_date"])
```

but this just produces the error: `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labelled Series objects`

I hope I've provided enough information for someone to help. Thanks very much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can groupby `account_id` and filter rows before the first `initial_balance` then `cumsum()` on `amount` column

```py
out = df.groupby('account_id').apply(lambda g: g[g['data_type'].eq('initial_balance').cumsum().eq(1)]).reset_index(drop=True)
out['amount'] = out.groupby('account_id')['amount'].cumsum()
```

```
print(out)

  account_id        data_type transaction_date  amount
0       1001  initial_balance       2022-04-01     100
1       1001          payment       2022-04-14      80
2       1002  initial_balance       2022-04-02     200
3       1002          payment       2022-04-13     180
4       1002          payment       2022-05-01     160
5       1002          payment       2022-05-03     140
6       1003  initial_balance       2022-04-10     150
7       1003          payment       2022-04-20     100
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this! It works like a dream. As you'll have seen from my attempt, I was trying to use `==` not `.eq()`. Could I just ask what the `.eq(1)` is doing after the `cumsum` ? Thanks again for such a quick reply. Much appreciated.

Comment: @the_abbot `cumsum` turns all the `False` after `True` to `1`. `.eq(1)` is to select `1` which aims to select `False` after `True`.

Comment: Thanks @Ynjxsjmh. Ah, OK I think I get it. So `cumsum` here is working on the True/False of the condition of `data_type == "initial_balance"` and setting all the False after the initial True to True. Then the `.eq(1)` is the filter which drops the rows before the initial True. I guess this is dependent on the original dataframe being ordered ascending by `transaction_date`. Thanks, I think I've got it. Proof will be if I can use the technique again myself! :-D

Answer (score 0):

This does the job.

```
grouped_df = df.groupby("account_id")
groups = []

for group in df["account_id"].unique():
  group_df = grouped_df.get_group(group)
  group_df = group_df.loc[group_df[group_df["data_type"] == "initial_balance"].index[0]:, :]
  group_df["amount"] = group_df["amount"].cumsum()
  groups.append(group_df)

df = pd.concat(groups)
```

Output -

|  | account_id | data_type | transaction_date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1001 | initial_balance | 2022-04-01 | 100 |
| 1 | 1001 | payment | 2022-04-14 | 80 |
| 3 | 1002 | initial_balance | 2022-04-02 | 200 |
| 4 | 1002 | payment | 2022-04-13 | 180 |
| 5 | 1002 | payment | 2022-05-01 | 160 |

Comment: Thanks for your response, Zero. As mentioned above, I've gone with the first reply for the moment, but I'll have a look at your method at some point as well. I have to confess to getting a little nervous about slicing in the way you're proposing, really just because I get myself a little lost. So it's probably a useful exercise for me to work through examples like yours to gain some confidence with the technique. Thanks again for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: @the_abbot Take your time to understand it, and let me know if you have any doubts! I too avoid doing the whole thing in one line cause...it's just unreadable but your question made me wanna get comfortable doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
m = (df['data_type'] == "initial_balance").groupby(df['account_id']).cummax()

df_out = df[m].groupby('account_id')['amount'].cumsum()\
              .reset_index(name='account_balance')\
              .merge(df, left_on='index', right_index=True)
df_out
```

OUtput:

```
   index  account_balance account_id        data_type transaction_date  amount
0      0              100       1001  initial_balance       2022-04-01     100
1      1               80       1001          payment       2022-04-14     -20
2      3              200       1002  initial_balance       2022-04-02     200
3      4              180       1002          payment       2022-04-13     -20
4      5              160       1002          payment       2022-05-01     -20
5      6              140       1002          payment       2022-05-03     -20
6      8              150       1003  initial_balance       2022-04-10     150
7      9              100       1003          payment       2022-04-20     -50
```

Details, create a boolean series that is true when data_type equals initial_balance, then groupby that series by account_id using cummax() to create mask for the original dataframe keep inital_balance and records after that per account_id.

Next, groupby that filtered dataframea and cumsum by account_id, merge this data back to original dataframe using inner join to drop unwanted records.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Scott. I've used the first answer for the time being, but will have a look at your solution when I have a chance. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @the_abbot No worries, as long as you get the help you need.  Have a blessed day.   Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks @Scott Boston, you too.